# how to override the background when using float element

Tags: html, css

I have a website footer, this is the code looks like:

```
<div className="App-footer-float">
  <div id="footer" className="App-footer">
    <Divider></Divider>
    <div>
      <Row justify="center" align="middle">
        <Col>
          <div>© 2022 Apple</div>
          <div>ICP 1700232-6</div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the css looks like:

```
.App-footer-float{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.App-footer{
  font-size: 0.3rem;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: "center";
  width: 100%;
}
```

this footer element are transparent, now I want to using the float element to override the background element. I have tried to set the background color in `App-footer-float`:

```
.App-footer-float{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

also tried to set the opacity and transparent, seems could not work. what should I do to make the footer element override the background and make it non-transparent?

Comment: [`float` has a specific meaning in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) so using it in a class name for an element that is not floating is very confusing.

Comment: `App-footer-float` appears to be a completely pointless element; all its content is `position`ed.